# Is it possible to create option menu when window is set to full screen?

Tags: android, fullscreen, oncreate, oncreateoptionsmenu

Is it possible to create option menu when window is set to full screen? And how do I set the window to full screen inside option menu?
Inside onCreate i had to  commandline the code because i was not able see the option menu when the screen is set to full screen.

see the code to understand why i need it.

```
public class FlashlightActivity extends Activity {

    ImageButton switchButton;

    private Camera camera;
    private boolean isFlashOn;
    private boolean hasFlash;
    Parameters params;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        //getWindow().setFlags(~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    //WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_flashlight);

        switchButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSwitch);
        // First check if device is supporting flashlight or not
        hasFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
                .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);

        if (!hasFlash) {
            // device doesn't support flash
            // Show alert message and close the application
            AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(FlashlightActivity.this)
                    .create();
            alert.setTitle("Error");
            alert.setMessage("Sorry, your device doesn't support flash light! Do you want to use your screen as alternitive?");
            alert.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        RelativeLayout wscreen =   (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.flashbg);

                            wscreen.removeAllViews();
                            wscreen.setBackgroundColor(0);

            WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
                            lp.screenBrightness = 1;
                            getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
                        }
                    });

            alert.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // closing the application
                            finish();
                        }
                    });

            alert.show();
            return;
        }

        // get the camera
        getCamera();

        // displaying button image
        toggleButtonImage();

        // Switch button click event to toggle flash on/off
        switchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isFlashOn) {
                    // turn off flash
                    turnOffFlash();
                } else {
                    // turn on flash
                    turnOnFlash();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // Get the camera
    private void getCamera() {
        if (camera == null) {
            try {
                camera = Camera.open();
                params = camera.getParameters();
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e("Camera Error. Failed to Open. Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    // Turning On flash
    private void turnOnFlash() {
        if (!isFlashOn) {
            if (camera == null || params == null) {
                return;
            }
            // play sound
            // playSound();

            params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            camera.setParameters(params);
            camera.startPreview();
            isFlashOn = true;

            // changing button/switch image
            toggleButtonImage();
        }

    }

    // Turning Off flash
    private void turnOffFlash() {
        if (isFlashOn) {
            if (camera == null || params == null) {
                return;
            }
            // play sound
            // playSound();

            params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            camera.setParameters(params);
            camera.stopPreview();
            isFlashOn = false;

            // changing button/switch image
            toggleButtonImage();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Toggle switch button images changing image states to on / off
     */
    private void toggleButtonImage() {
        if (isFlashOn) {
            switchButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.flashlight_on);
        } else {
            switchButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.flashlight_off);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // on pause turn off the flash
        turnOffFlash();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // on resume turn on the flash
        if (hasFlash)
            turnOnFlash();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // on starting the app get the camera params
        getCamera();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // on stop release the camera
        if (camera != null) {
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
    }



      @Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
          // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
     // getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.flashlight, menu); return true; 
          menu.add("Use alternative flashlight");
          return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
          }

      @Override  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem Item)
      {  switch (Item.getItemId()) {
      case 0:


          RelativeLayout wscreen = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.flashbg);

            wscreen.removeAllViews();
            wscreen.setBackgroundColor(0);

            WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
            lp.screenBrightness = 1;
          getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

          return true;
      default:
          return super.onOptionsItemSelected(Item);
  } 

      }

      }
```